# How can I disable the trackball?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable trackball click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423948/disable-trackball-click-in-android)

How can I disable the trackball in my app? I only want the buttons to work when you click them using the touchscreen.

Comment: I would recommend not doing that.  The trackball provides a way for people with vision or movement disabilities to access the Android apps even if they can't see, or move to touch the screen.  Why don't you want the trackball to be used?

Answer (score 1):

You might try catching the track ball event and returning true that it was handled. Not sure if it works though.

```
    @Override public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks but It doesn't work :(