# Disable trackball programmatically

Tags: android, events, trackball

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable trackball click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423948/disable-trackball-click-in-android)

Is there any way to completely disable trackball interaction programmatically? I don't need my app to respond trackball events. At the moment I put

`public boolean dispatchTrackballEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }`

in my activity, but still sometimes i receive these event. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, but there is no working solution there

Comment: OP said `Edit: here's a solution`. And if you saw the question, then you should have posted there I think.

Comment: The question there was related with disabling events on single progress bar. I need global solution to disable trackball all over my app. I don't think these question are so related